# Erro na codificação/decodificação charset entre DB2 e Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, codificação-de-caracteres, db2

**Meu problema:**
Tenho uma aplicação Node que envia mensagens para um Whatsapp específico (funciona normalmente, sem erro de caracteres). Porém ao realizar uma consulta no banco de dados (IBM DB2) e enviar esses dados ao cliente esse símbolo aparece:�. Se eu converter para utf-8 isto aparece: ï¿½ .
Esses símbolos aparecem exatamente onde deveria ser ç e vogais acentuadas.

Para conexão com o banco utilizo o pacote ibm_db: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm_db

Testes:

**(1)** - Verifiquei o charset do banco de dados pelo charset-detector, esse foi o retorno:

````
  CharsetMatch {
    confidence: 15,
    charsetName: 'UTF-8',
    lang: undefined
  },
  CharsetMatch { confidence: 10, charsetName: 'Shift_JIS', lang: 'ja' },
  CharsetMatch { confidence: 10, charsetName: 'GB18030', lang: 'zh' },
  CharsetMatch { confidence: 10, charsetName: 'EUC-JP', lang: 'ja' },
  CharsetMatch { confidence: 10, charsetName: 'EUC-KR', lang: 'ko' },
  CharsetMatch { confidence: 10, charsetName: 'Big5', lang: 'zh' }
] ```

**(2)** - Tentei codificar e decodificar utilizando os pacotes:

**a)** utf8: 
 

    ```const utf8 = require('utf8')
    const convertUTF8 = (value) =>{
        value = value.toString()
        value =  utf8.encode(value)
        return utf8.decode(value)
    } // retorno ï¿½ -> obs:tentei codificar e decodificar depois disso
    ```

**b)** Buffer nativo do Node:

    ```const convertUTF8 = (value) =>{
        value = value.toString()
        const buf = Buffer.from(value,'utf8')
        return buf
        
    } // retorno � obs:chutei -> Buffer.from(value,'latin1') também, mesmo erro. E também Buffer.from(value,'utf16le') sem sucesso
    ```

**c)** stringDecoder:

    ```const { StringDecoder } = require('string_decoder');
    const decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8');
    const convertUTF8 = (value) =>{
        value = value.toString()
        return decoder.end(value)   
    }// retorno �
    /*
    fiz também assim:
    
        const convertUTF8 = (value) =>{
            value = value.toString()
            const str = Buffer.from(value)
            console.log(decoder.end(str))
            return str
        
    } tive o mesmo erro
    */
    ```

**d)** Usei também o encov, mas não tenho o código para mostrar. Seu resultado foi igual aos outros

**NOTA:** *Se eu criar uma string e enviar como mensagem para o usuário ele recebe normalmente, então acredito que esse erro esteja acontecendo entre o db2 e o node.*

Então já não sei o que fazer, procurei por diversas soluções e nenhuma me atendeu.

Disponibilizo meu repositório para análise: https://github.com/GilbertoTADS/botmaker-chat.git

**Nova Informação:** Fiz uma query no banco em que consultar os dados já retirava os acentos e troca o çÇ pelo cC. Mas o problema continua.

**QUERY CITADA(parte relevante) ->** 

    ```const strQuery = `SELECT
            [(..outros campos aqui...)],
            LOWER(TRANSLATE(pv.DESCRICAOPRODUTO,
            'SZszYACEIOUAEIOUAEIOUAOEUIONYaaceiouaeiouaeiouaoeuionyy Cc',
            'ŠŽšžŸÁÇÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÂÊÎÔÛÃÕËÜÏÖÑÝåáçéíóúàèìòùâêîôûãõëüïöñýÿºÇç')) AS DESCRICAOPRODUTO
        FROM [(...continua...)]```
````

Comment: Qual é o codeset e colation do banco de dados?

Comment: Utilizo o Dbeaver para me conectar ao db2

Comment: @Danizavtz, como faço para ver meu codeset?

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVIDO!!!
Após muita leitura, minha solução era muito simples.
Basta configurar:

`process.env.DB2CODEPAGE = 1208;`
antes de:
`ibmdb.open(connStr)`

E, pinba! Funcionou direitinho.
Deixei registrado pois quem quiser pode tentar também.